# Type of conduit box to use for a Ring doorbell + keyed entry

Tags: electrical, conduit

I have a powered gate at the front of my property and its well overdue to replace/upgrade the intercom system. I would like to install a ring doorbell system and a keyswitch to open the gate.

The current installation already has a doorbell button (with power), a defunct nutone intercom microphone/speaker, and a contact closure keyswitch for opening the gate. This is installed in an intercom style enclosure, screwed onto a 1" threaded pipe. The pipe is cemented into the driveway wall.

Lets say I remove the entire intercom enclosure. Can you recommend a style or model of enclosure to put in its place?

Comment: The type of box if only a ring type doorbell would be a Single gang Bell box. These can be found with 1" threaded holes and with the proper gasket and cover would be waterproof. If you have additional devices like the key switch a double gang Bell box would be my next choice. Make sure to plug any unused holes in the bell box, I use a little RTV or silicone sealer on the threads on the top of the box so water cannot get in if sitting level water will pool in the small depression and over time may get in to your electronics, this is why I take the extra step of sealing the threads.

Comment: Thanks Ed, Bell boxes was the product I was looking for. Post this as an answer if you want the reputation.

Comment: I would say the ruling *size* would be the one that fits your application.  As for type, I would go straight for the aluminum outdoor ones with threaded entry/exit holes, that have a 1" pipe thread.  Home Depot won't have those, I'd go to a proper electrical supply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested : The type of box if only a ring type doorbell would be a Single gang Bell box. These can be found with 1" threaded holes and with the proper gasket and cover would be waterproof. If you have additional devices like the key switch a double gang Bell box would be my next choice. Make sure to plug any unused holes in the bell box, I use a little RTV or silicone sealer on the threads on the top of the box so water cannot get in if sitting level water will pool in the small depression and over time may get in to your electronics, this is why I take the extra step of sealing the threads